# AWS - Route to multiple ports on a single instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

AWS' Application Load Balancer has the feature to `Route to multiple ports on a single instance`.

Can anyone name a few use cases when you might use this feature?

Comment: Docker Containers?

Comment: Want to expand?

Comment: Multiple, identical containers.  Each serving the same application.  So, instead of having multiple VMs, each hosting a copy of the "app", you have less VMs but more densely packed with containers hosting the "app".  It's a different way of looking at app updates, especially if you treat the containers as cattle and immutable.  Create a new container with the new version of the "app" and "roll" the new version across the dozens of copies across your environment without too much downtime on each container.

Comment: Each "app" has to listen on a different port on the host, thus the one-to-many mapping of the AWS LB.

Comment: So container 1 port 80 maps to instance port 80, container 2 port 80 maps to instance port 81, etc...?

Comment: Something like that.  I'm not familiar with how AWS and it's LB handles Container managers such as Kubernetes and Swarm that manage the containers themselves and their networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ports on the same host is critical when using a Docker scheduler such as Amazon EC2 Container Service (ECS), where you don't know beforehand what port #'s will be assigned, on what hosts, and may end up with multiple instances per host.

For smaller applications it allows you to perform a more graceful rolling update as you can launch the new instance before retiring the prior instance, on the same host.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes where webapps are being served there may be additional API services on the same device using a different port. In this case you could use URL redirection within the load balancer so that default/unrouted HTTPS traffic goes straight through to 443 whilst /api/ goes through to 8443 for example. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules) for more examples of what can be achieved with listener rules.